# Access Symfony/web/config.php from other address than localhost?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I'm currently testing different PHP frameworks to see witch on my going to use for my next project. I just installed Symfony2 on my web server. When trying to access the `Symfony/web/config.php` file, Symfony blocks this file from being edited by any other than localhost. Of cures there is no gui on my server, so a visual config is quite usless without a browser.

Is there a way to call access the `Symfony/web/config.php` file from any other address than loclhost?

Comment: You can do some port-forwarding [like this guy did](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/how-to-configure-symfony-2-0-on-ubuntu-server-2011-4/).

Comment: @hakre Great article! Thanks! Just the setup I'm using too (Ubuntu 11.04)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can add your own host to that configuration so you can open it with your browser.

To do so, add your host (that is your public WAN IP, e.g. [you can google it](https://www.google.com/search?noj=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=my+ip&oq=my+ip)) into the [`config.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/42e7fddc57c319723f37390e7fcbe2eb0c8d8517/web/config.php) file. It's the array of hostnames on top, see the *'my very own ip'* example entry:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
    'my very own ip',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

You should then be able to access the script on your server.

Comment: down voting this because this file says right at the top to not edit it, because it gets overwritten during composer install.  If you are deploying to a remote server this wont work.

Comment: @dorgan: It did not for the file referenced in the answer years ago and next to that, these settings are normally not permanent anyway.

Answer (score 11):

If you are not sure from which ip you are connecting, use

`var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`

Comment: in google enter: "my ip" - you can see it before the first search result then.