# How do I access to symfony config.php remotely?

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have set up Symfony in bitnami on Amazon EC2. Now I want to access `web/config.php`, but was told the file can only be run via localhost.

And I also tried to log on remote desktop of EC2, but failed. So now how can I ensure symfony is all good on server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Symfony/web/config.php from other address than localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383223/access-symfony-web-config-php-from-other-address-than-localhost)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `config.php` and edit following code

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

You can either add the IP Address oft the remote server or just comment out this piece of code. Consider the last advice is not recommended for security reasons.

Comment: If you edit the file, reset it back to the original version after checking the configuration. You don't want everybody to have access to your configuration

Answer (score 0):

First use htpasswd to protect your production site. Edit the file config.php and remove.