# 500 internal error when accessing symfony2 app on amazon ec2

Tags: symfony, bitnami

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access to symfony config.php remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870243/how-do-i-access-to-symfony-config-php-remotely)

I uploaded sandbox to bitnami AMI on amazon ec2, but got "500 internal error" when I enter into web/index.php, how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean that you are accessing the site via www.domain.com/web/index.php? If so, point your document root to the web folder, and not its parent. (Ah, just noticed you're using version 2 - not sure how that is structured. Nevertheless, the same applies - we'll probably need more detail to help you here).

Comment: @thecatontheflat There is nothing in logs folder..

Comment: And in the apache log files is there not more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check **config.php**? What recommendations where listed there?

First you never access `web/index.php`. You have to set your document root to point to the **web** folder. This is important due security reasons.

Second a 500 Server Error is also likely to be a permission problem. You webserver needs to have rights to execute the files. On debian linux I would set permissions like this

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/www.example.com/web
```

while the webserver is running with www-data as user/group.

Comment: I have pointed to web folder. I am using Bitvise to SSH connect to the server, and may I change the folder permission to 755 directly by bitvise GUI operation?

Comment: When you access config.php in webbrowser it will tell you if the webserver has no permission. So check this first!

Comment: Because I am using sandbox, and there is no config.php in web folder, so I just copy config.php and comment "127.0.0.1" stuff, and checked. No good news.

Comment: NOtice that in BitNami apache is running as 'daemon' user not 'www-data'.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the following lines in your config.php for debugging:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

Those block all access from outside..

Comment: I know that in the default symfony pachage, but here I used the sandbox, and I cannot check logs.