# Install Symfony on remote server

Tags: apache, symfony

I'm trying to evaluate Symfony 2 (2.1.7). I'm installing it following [the download instructions](http://symfony.com/download) on an EC2 instance that is already running PHP 5.3.20 on Apache.

I'm stuck on the second step of the README.md: "Access the `config.php` script from a browser". The readme assumes a local installation and provides a sample URL to the localhost: `http://localhost/path/to/symfony/app/web/config.php`.

Since I'm on a remote server, I try to access the config.php file using the relevant URL: `http://mysite.com/Symfony/app/check.php`, which returns this message:

  **Forbidden**
  You don't have permission to access /Symfony/app/check.php on this server.

I tried to apply the answer from [How do I access to symfony config.php remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870243/how-do-i-access-to-symfony-config-php-remotely) by adding what PHP reports back as my REMOTE_ADDR, but that doesn't change the message.

What do I do now?

Comment: Check your external ip and add it to the allowed ones (google "my ip" and you will find thousands of websites offering this service)

Comment: It seems to me that I have to allow Apache to serve the file before I even have to wrestle with the PHP code...

Comment: More simple, comment the php restriction. But *DO NOT FORGET* to uncomment it back once you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In symfony, the web folder is supposed to be your webroot. So, if you want to access \project\web\config.php, you should point your browser to http://www.example.com/config.php.

If that doesnt work, apache is probably configured incorrectly. make sure it it is pointed at your web directory, not your project directory.

*edit* As you mention in your question, you will also need to edit the config.php file to allow remote access. You can comment those lines out, or add your IP to the whitelist.

*edit2* Many webhosts don't allow you to specify your webroot. In that situation, you can put the Symfony files in a different directory and create a symlink between the Symfony web directory and your webroot.

Comment: Oooohhhh....so if I already had a web root (`/var/www/html`), and I used composer to install Symfony at `/var/www/html/Symfony`...do I need to set up a virtual directory? Or just edit folder/file permissions since Symfony is in a subfolder of the web root? Where *should* I have installed Symfony, given my pre-existing web root?

Comment: You would probably want to install symfony in the www directory, and then symlink www/html to www/web. The purpose of this file structure is to keep your source files completely outside of web accessible directories.

Comment: On second thought, I would put symfony in a completely different directory and then symlink. Just to keep the folder names more meaningful.

Comment: Documentation about solution here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html